# How to dynamically create the list of the columns to include in select?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to "generate" a spark query in this way

```
  def stdizedOperationmode(sqLContext: SQLContext,withrul: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    // see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html
    import sqLContext.implicits._
    val AZ: Column  = lit(0.00000001)

    def opMode(id:Int): Column = {
      (column("s"+id) - coalesce(column("a"+id) / column("sd"+id), column("a"+id) / lit(AZ))).as("std"+id)
    }

    // add the 21 std<i> columns based on s<i> - (a<id>/sd<id>)
    val columns: IndexedSeq[Column] = 1 to 21 map(id => opMode(id))

    val withStd = withrul.select(columns:_*)

    withStd
  }
```

Question how do I add  "all other columns" (*) idea: something like  `withrul.select('* :+ columns:_*)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following :

```scala
// add the 21 std<i> columns based on s<i> - (a<id>/sd<id>)

val columns: IndexedSeq[Column] = 1 to 21 map(id => opMode(id))

val selectAll: Array[Column] = (for {
  i <- withrul.columns
} yield withrul(i)) union columns.toSeq

val withStd = withrul.select(selectAll :_*)
```

The second line will yeild all the columns from withrul adding them with column as a Seq[Column]

You are not obliged to create a value to return it afterward, can replace the last 2 lines with :

```scala
withrul.select(selectAll : _*)
```

Comment: I'd replace `for...yield` to `union` later with `map`. I'd also recommend `(1 to 21).map(opMode)`.